# HONDA CRV 2014/15 Unknown Off Button

Tags: honda, crv

I have an "off" button under my steering wheel below my parking sensor and econ buttons but higher than my petrol cap opener. It just says off and it has a symbol of a car on it and what looks like the antenna or airwaves coming out of the roof of the picture.
Any ideas? i have searched my manual but cannot see it.
Here's hoping!
AMM

Comment: A picture? And I can't see why they would leave it out of the manual...

Comment: Could this be a custom alarm system? The "airwaves" could symbol sound emitting from the car...

Answer (score 1):

I know you mention that the "waves" appeared to be coming from the roof in the picture but given everything else you describe about it (including location) I wonder whether it's actually this:

[image: Culprit?]

If so then that's the Vehicle Stability Assist (VSA) Off button - pressing that disables the stability control on the car until the car is turned off.